# Making directories with command line on C#

Tags: c#, cmd

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "md " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start ();
```

I'm attempting to make a directory on the desktop with this command, it doesn't make one however. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Why are you doing it this way, just out of curiosity?  .NET has built-in capabilities for manipulating the file system (e.g. creating directories, etc.)

Comment: for security reasons, I'm testing a basic command to exec other ones

Comment: You are mixing two approaches and that is probably your problem. Either try what @roryap suggest or go pure command line commands.

Comment: You haven't provided it the name of the directory to make, just the path to the desktop.  That already exists.

Comment: And your statement "for security reasons" doesn't make sense.  What "security" are you talking about?

Comment: Can you please add link to source where you've got CMD arguments from? It does not look anywhere close to correct to me.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), 
    "my new folder name"));
```

Always prefer using the .NET class library instead of invoking external processes to do your work, unless you have a *very specific* reason not to do so.

---

One of the reasons your code is not working is because you are using the wrong syntax for `cmd.exe`.  In order to pass a command as an argument, you have to use the following with the `/K` switch (use `cmd /?` for more information):

```
cmd.exe /K MD "c:\test\blah"
```

Another reason your code won't work is that the path you're providing to the `MD` command is just the path to the desktop itself:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
```

You have forgotten to append the name of the folder you want to create *on* the desktop.